# How do I return to a Form that has constructors

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to C# and have this problem which I have been struggling with for almost a week now (Before you ask ...... I have continued with my project and then come back to this issue which is why it has been so long)

So my project has 14 Forms

My problem is as follows

Form1 Code:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.Show();
this.Close();
```

Form2 Code:

```
Form3 frm3 = new Form3(lbl1.Text, lbl2.Text, lbl3.Text);
frm3.Show();
this.Close();
```

Form3 Code:

```
Form4 frm4 = new Form4;
frm4.Show();
this.Close();
```

After closing Form4 I need to go back to Form3 BUT if I was to code the following in Form4

Form4 Code:

```
Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
frm3.Show();
this.close();
```

I get an error that tells me:

"...............does not contain a constructor that contains 0 arguments"

I understand what the message is saying but I do not know how to get around it

Comment: You need to understand that you _can't_ get around it! Your entire approach is wrong. Maybe Form4 is _modal_, such that when Form3 shows Form4, nothing can happen on Form3 until Form4 is finished? In that case, use `frm4.ShowDialog(this)` instead of `frm4.Show()`.

Comment: Your error is telling you that the class Form3 doesn't have a constructor without parameters. From your code it seems Form3 has a constructor that receives 3 strings (new Form3(lbl1.Text, lbl2.Text, lbl3.Text)). In order for new Form3() to work, you need to have declared a parameter-less constructor: public Form3() {/* constructor logic here */}. That is the reason for the error. Beyond that, from your code it seems you need to hold a reference to Form3, so when you close Form4 you can tell Form3 to show up again, as some people below has suggested already.

Comment: There are lots of solutions to this, but your approach is completely wrong. There shouldn't be a reason for you to need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Form3 has that constructor, it means that it needs those three strings initialize properly:

```
Form3 frm3 = new Form3(lbl1.Text, lbl2.Text, lbl3.Text);
```

So it makes no sense to create a new copy of `Form3` without those strings.

On the other hand, what I think you *really* mean is that you don't want to *close* Form3, only to *hide* it, then show it later. The usual way of doing this is to have a master Form which holds instances of the sub-forms as members or properties.

`MainForm` code:

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1;
Form2 frm2 = new Form2;
Form3 frm3 = new Form3("", "", ""); // start with default values
Form4 frm4 = new Form4;
```

`Form1` code:

```
this.Hide();
MainForm.frm2.Show();
```

`Form2` code:

```
this.Hide();
MainForm.frm3 = new Form3(lbl1.Text, lbl2.Text, lbl3.Text); // use values from frm2
MainForm.frm3.Show();
```

`Form4` code:

```
this.Hide();
MainForm.frm3.Show();
```

Comment: Thank you all. Being new to this I guess that I didnt really know how to explain myself properly. For the mostpart what has been said I am aware of But the answer from egrunin best answers the question that I didnt know how to ask properly. Again thank you all .Regards JJ

Comment: OK I have created a new Form " MasterForm " and I have loaded all the forms into this form as per above. Now when I write MasterForm.frm3(lbl1.Text, lbl2.Text, lbl3.Text); in Form2 I get an error "frm3 does not contain a definition for Form3" but if I recode it Form3 frm3 = new Form3(with parameters here)  then the error goes away. What am Idoing wrong???    JJ

Comment: The problem in your last comment is one of syntax. `MasterForm.frm3(lbl1.Text, lbl2.Text, lbl3.Text);` makes no sense, because it means "call the method `MasterForm.frm3()`" when no such method exists. On the other hand, `Form3 frm3 = new Form3(...)` means "construct a new instance of Form3 and store a reference to it in the variable `frm3`", which does make sense.

Comment: Hi engrunin. Obviously I have misunderstood your answer, which shows a form called MainForm that holds all the new instances of the other forms. Your example then shows code in Form 1 calling Form2 by using the MainForm Class  name eg MainForm.frm2.Show();. Either way I have misunderstood either your answer or your code. Forgive my lack of knowledge and thank you for your help. Regards JJ

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two options.

1) Call the existing constructor with proper parameters as you do on Form2

2) Create a constructor with no parameters

```
public Form3()
{ 
     // constructor logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Form properties to `Form4` to hold the instance of `Form3`

```
public Form frmHolder { get; set; }
```

Form3

```
Form4 frm4 = new Form4();
frm4.frmHolder = this;
frm4.Show();
this.Close();
```

Form4

```
Form3 frm3 = frmHolder;
frm3.Show();
this.close();
```

Comment: Hi Leonel. I am currenty doing it this way but I because the parameters in Form1 (which are being sent to a file held in Form3) are different to the parameters in Form4 (being sent to the same file held in Form3 but with updated information) I am having the problem. JJ